# Activating extension 'PublisherName.extensionName' failed: command 'extensionName.commandName' already exists

Tags: vscode-extensions

I've been developing [my VS Code extension](https://github.com/Phrogz/visual-scxml-editor) without publishing it. It just got to a point where it's releasable, and in doing so I had to add a `"publisher": "Phrogz"` key to my `package.json`. This broke commands in the extension; when I run the first command, VS Code shows the error:

```
Activating extension 'Phrogz.visual-scxml-editor' failed:
command 'visual-scxml-editor.showEditor' already exists.
```

and none of my commands work any more.

What is going on; how do I fix this (other than deleting the `publisher`)?

---

*Update: the problem occurs on my Linux desktop, but my macOS laptop does not exhibit the same symptom. Very curious!*

Comment: Did you create the `publisher` ala https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#create-a-publisher?

Comment: I installed your extension and on an `test.xml` file I ran the `SCXML Editor: Open to the Side` command.  It opened a `SCXML.test.xml` file to the side.  No error message.  At least that command works, any other command I can test?.

Comment: @Mark Weird! Maybe it only happens when locally developing the extension? If you've the time, can you clone the git repo, open in VS Code, hit F5 to launch the extension in another VS Code instance, and there open an SCXML file (e.g. `docs/example.scxml`) and issue the `Open to the Side` command?

Comment: To answer your first question: yes, I followed the instructions as best I could, including creating an Azure account, creating a publisher, creating a private token, and (not on this computer) running `vsce login Phrogz` successfully.

Comment: Alternatively, if the extension worked then after running `Open to the Side` there should be a pile of commands prefixed with `SCXML Editor` available in the command list.

Comment: When  `SCXML.test.xml` (and empty) is focused I get 6 `SCXML` commands in the Command Palette, 9 total in `Keyboard Shortcuts`, obviously 3 without the `when` clause requirement.